# How to display QtChartView in window with other widgets?

Tags: c++, qt

I followed the following youtube tutorial (succesfully) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHn3ZTWcyXk&t=13m33s. I'm essentially trying to do the exact same thing as in the tutorial, however this time in a bigger window which already contains a bunch of widgets and stuff. I call the below function in the class constructor. This does however not display the data in the ui->graphview which is a QChartView.

```
void RecordWidget::setupGraph(){

    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
    series->append(0, 16);
    series->append(1, 25);
    series->append(2, 24);
    series->append(3, 19);
    series->append(4, 33);
    series->append(5, 25);
    series->append(6, 34);

    // Create chart, add data, hide legend, and add axis
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();

    // Customize the title font
    QFont font;
    font.setPixelSize(18);
    chart->setTitleFont(font);
    chart->setTitleBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
    chart->setTitle("Barry Bonds HRs as Pirate");

    // Change the line color and weight
    QPen pen(QRgb(0x000000));
    pen.setWidth(5);
    series->setPen(pen);

    chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations);

    // Change the x axis categories
    QCategoryAxis *axisX = new QCategoryAxis();
    axisX->append("1986",0);
    axisX->append("1987",1);
    axisX->append("1988",2);
    axisX->append("1989",3);
    axisX->append("1990",4);
    axisX->append("1991",5);
    axisX->append("1992",6);
    chart->setAxisX(axisX, series);

    // Used to display the chart
    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    ui->graphView = chartView;
    ui->graphView->show();
    ui->graphView->setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Do not set your graphView as the central widget. It has to be in a layout that contains the rest of your ui. See: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
ui->graphView->setChart(chart);
```

instead of

```
QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
ui->graphView = chartView;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ui->graphView` already in layout when you assign `ui->graphView = chartView;`. You just change the pointer. Instead you have to initially create `ui->graphView` as `QChartView`